# Core Data MVVM Example

Tags: ios, swift

Is this good or bad code for MVVM pattern with Core Data. For example i have Category+CoreDataClass.swift and CategoryDataProperties.swift; thats my

```
public class Account: NSManagedObject {
   //what should i write here; any clue
}

extension Account {
@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Category> {
            return NSFetchRequest< Category >(entityName: "Category")
        }        
        @NSManaged public var categoryId: Int64
        @NSManaged public var categoryTitle: String        
    }
```

Model = Category

```
class CategoryViewModel{
   var category:Category() //
   var categories: [Category]()
   func AddCategory(category) {
         //pass category to CoreData save method in CoreDataService.swift
       }
}
```

and ViewModel is used in Single Screen with two textField named categoryId,categoryName(UIView)

```
class CategoryVC:  UITableViewController {
    var  vm: CategoryViewModel!
}
```